# Show a pop-up that contains details of every row in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have an html table like this:

```html
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped">
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${listeCollabDeRrh}" var="collab">
        <tr>
            <td>${collab.matricule }</td>
            <td>${collab.nom }</td>
            <td>${collab.prenom}</td>
            <td hidden="true">${collab.bu.getNomBU()}</td>
            <td hidden="true">${collab.contact}</td>
            <td hidden="true">${collab.dateEmbauche}</td>
            <td>
                <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Details">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Details"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-color"></span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If I click on details button I will have the pop-up which contains all the details of a row:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Matricule</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Pronom</th>
        <th>BU</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Date d'ambauche</th>
        <th>RRH</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>matricule of collab</td>
            <td>nom of collab</td>
            <td>prenom of collab</td>
            <td>bu of collab</td>
            <td>contact of collab</td>
            <td>dateEmbauche of collab</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that the HTML table and the details pop-up are in the same jsp page. I think that I can use the controller in the server side with a form.

How can I show the details pop-up when I press the details button of a row?

Comment: Try to move the pop-up to a separated page.

Comment: I cant,the pages are fixed by client.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant is to use jQuery. And information read from server just if user click on button.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

invest your time for this and make better, faster and data low profile applications. 
But if you cannot use, Farhan have nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it's for all of the tables on the UI:

```
<script>
var cells=document.getElementsbyTagName("td");
for(i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
cells[i].onclick=function(){alert(this.innerHTML);};
}
</script>
```

Keep the HTML table structure normal. No need to call any functions over there.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".detail_button").on("click",function(){
     var parentTr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var counter = 1;
        $("td", $(parentTr)).each(function(){
         if(!($(this).hasClass("detail_td"))){
                $(".modal-body tr td:nth-child("+counter+")").text($(this).text());
             counter++;
            }
        $(".modal-body").show();
  $("#bodytable").hide();
  
        });
    });
 
 $("#hide_popup").on("click",function(){
  $(".modal-body").hide();
  $("#bodytable").show();
 });
    
});
```

```css
.modal-body{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
<input type="button" id="hide_popup" value="Hide Popup"/>
<div style="clear"></div>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Matricule</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Pronom</th>
        <th>BU</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Date d'ambauche</th>
        <th>RRH</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<table id="bodytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Matricule</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Pronom</th>
        <th>BU</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Date d'ambauche</th>
        <th>RRH</th>
        <th>Detail</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="detail_td">
                <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Details">
                    <button class="detail_button btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Details"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-color">Detail</span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="detail_td">
                <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Details">
                    <button class="detail_button btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Details"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-color">Detail</span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

As per my understanding you want to show relevant row data in popup on detail button click. if not then please correct me
HTML

```
    <div class="modal-body">
<input type="button" id="hide_popup" value="Hide Popup"/>
<div style="clear"></div>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Matricule</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Pronom</th>
        <th>BU</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Date d'ambauche</th>
        <th>RRH</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<table id="bodytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Matricule</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Pronom</th>
        <th>BU</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Date d'ambauche</th>
        <th>RRH</th>
        <th>Detail</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="detail_td">
                <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Details">
                    <button class="detail_button btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Details">   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-color">Detail</span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="detail_td">
                <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Details">
                    <button class="detail_button btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Details">   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-color">Detail</span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".detail_button").on("click",function(){
    var parentTr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var counter = 1;
    $("td", $(parentTr)).each(function(){
        if(!($(this).hasClass("detail_td"))){
            $(".modal-body tr td:nth-child("+counter+")").text($(this).text());
            counter++;
        }
    $(".modal-body").show();
    $("#bodytable").hide();

    });
});

$("#hide_popup").on("click",function(){
    $(".modal-body").hide();
    $("#bodytable").show();
});

});
```

CSS

```
.modal-body{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0px;
}
```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/daf2rLvh/3/

Comment: it's intersting,I will try it and i will give you a feedback,thank very much Mr.Farhan.

Comment: if you don't want to hide base table then remove $("#bodytable").hide(); and  $("#bodytable").show(); from Jquery code. also add styling to popup like page overlay